# Phonegap for Online Web Application

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

I am developing a Sencha Touch 2 HTML5 hybrid application with PhoneGap (currently, it is being developed for iOS). Here, I am using PhoneGap for accessing camera, contacts and etc...

My question: I need to develop the same application as mobile web application with access of camera contacts. These native mobile facilities (camera, contacts and etc...) should be accessible from the web application (which is running on mobile's web browser)

Is this possible with Phonegap or do we have any other framework for achieving this?

-Sridhar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't access everything with a webapp!
camera can be supported (depend of the mobile browser, and the user configuration), but contacts, forexemple, won't be accessible!
it's part of the web security...